# How should I work with repositories that squash pull requests on merge, when I have local branches based on open pull requests?

Tags: git, github, rebase

When working on git bases where all pull requests must be squashed before merging, I run into the following issue.

The issue occurs when I have an open pull request A and I'm working on a second pull request B that's based off of the changes in A.

After pull request A is merged into origin/main, I guess I should find all local branches that were based on A, and do `rebase <commit_from_A_that_branch_was_based_on> --onto origin/main`.

However, I often forget to do that, or I might not know which commit to rebase from. Now when I do `merge origin/main` from my branch B that was based on A, I'll get merge conflicts that I would have liked to avoid.

Is there a workflow, tool or script that can mitigate this issue?

Answer (score 1):

In a so complex scenario I suggest you, based on my own experience, to avoid squashing PRs, and keeping commits as low in number as possibile, limiting them at real units on changes which make sense in the project history.

May seem a banal answer, but it relies on the principle of fair and consistent usage of git.